# Spring Boot multipart api with application/json content-type

Tags: spring-boot, rest, postman, multipartform-data, swagger-ui

I have a simple controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class StudentServiceController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/students", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<String> storeStudent(@RequestPart("student") Student student) {
        System.out.println(student);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Student stored", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

and

```
@Data
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

With postman I have to use

[image]

And it works.  But I have to set content-type to application/json.  If I leave it to auto it is not working beacause there is no content-type in the received request.

```
2021-12-03 08:58:18.926 DEBUG 8336 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /api/students HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: b38c1efa-9a31-4e86-8e59-847d3a560e19
Host: 127.0.0.1:8090
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------039414868417265521836158
Content-Length: 202

----------------------------039414868417265521836158
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="student"

{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}
----------------------------039414868417265521836158--
]
2021-12-03 08:58:18.932  WARN 8336 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]
```

What's the goal of the auto then ?

With swagger it seems there is no way to have it working for the same reason (and I cannot set the part type)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/students' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'student={
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string"
}'
```

Is there a way to have swagger working ?

Comment: Why do you need a Multipart Form Data endpoint to receive JSON?

Comment: Because I also intend to add a multipart file.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution?